# How to display the anchor URL and Title based in a webpage using XSLT from an XML file and insert the image

Tags: html, asp.net, xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Collection>
    <Content>
        <ID>2779</ID>
        <Type>Content</Type>
        <Title>Article One</Title>
        <QuickLink>/template.aspx?id=2779</QuickLink>
        <Teaser />
        <Html>
            <root>
                <NewsArticle>
                    <artTitle>The Comprehensive Breast Center: Quality Care on the Fast Track</artTitle>
                    <artThumb>
                        <img alt="Thumb Article One" src="/uploadedImages/Test/News/artOne.png?n=5954" />
                    </artThumb>
                    <artFull />
                    <releaseDate />
                    <contactName />
                    <contactPhone />
                    <contactEmail />
                    <artTeaser>The National Cancer Institute estimates that a woman in the United States has a 1 in 8 chance of developing invasive breast cancer</artTeaser>
                    <artText>
                        <p>The Comprehensive Breast Center: Quality Care on 
the Fast Track</p>
                        <p>
```

How can I display the `href` tag to have the `QuickLink` XML tag and the `title` tag to have the `artTitle`?

Here is the XSLT line I want to modify:

```
<a href="" title=""><xsl:value-of select="Html/root/NewsArticle/artTitle" /></a>
```

I am able to see the text but the `href` and `title` are empty.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template name="homeArticleThumb" match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="Collection/Content">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3" style="height: 150px;">
      <div class="test2n" style="height: 100%;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 28% padding-right: 2%; height: 100%;">
          <img>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
              <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/NewsArticle/artThumb" />
            </xsl:attribute>
          </img>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 58%; height: 100%;">
          <div style="width: 100%; height: 48%; padding-bottom: 2%; text-align: left;">

            <a href="" title="">
              <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/NewsArticle/artTitle" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div style="width: 100%; height: 48%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipses; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left">
            <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/NewsArticle/artTeaser" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show us the input XML and the XSLT you used with the expected output.

Comment: Can you show us the  full XSLT, and the expected output?

Comment: I updated my question also. I would like to populate the link as well as the image. neither of them are working. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curly braces("{","}") to get the xpath evaluated as attributes' values.

```
<a href="{QuickLink}" title="{Html/root/NewsArticle/artTitle}">..</a>
```

Comment: The `..` can be a XSL:value-of?

Comment: Yes. It is like "anything".. :)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Would you be able to show me how to display the image?